# Let $p\ge 1$ and suppose that $X_n \to X$ in probability. If there exists $Y\in L^p$ such that $|X_n|\le Y$. Prove that $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$.

Tags: probability, analysis

> Let $p\ge 1$ and suppose that $X_n \to X$ in probability. If there exists $Y\in L^p$ such that $|X_n|\le Y$. Prove that $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$.

I try to prove it as follows. Fix $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\int |X_n-X|^p dP=\int_{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon}|X_n-X|^p dP+\int_{|X_n-X|> \epsilon}|X_n-X|^p dP
$$
$$
\le \epsilon^p+\int_{|X_n-X|> \epsilon}(2Y)^p dP
$$

But I am stuck in there....

Comment: Dominated convergence along a subsequence?

Comment: Can you explain how to use DCT? Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374830/dominated-convergence-theorem-with-almost-surely-replaced-by-convergence-in-p